# Replace "You have already voted to close ...." after retracting vote

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

After retracting a close vote, the close dialog says *You have already voted to close this question*. But this statement is false as we retracted our vote, we are no longer able to vote again and our vote is not counted because we retracted it.

Can it be replaced to ***"You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote"*** or something similar?

Currently it looks like this:

[image: current closed dialog]

This is what I am expecting:

[image: proposed closed dialog]

This looks more reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the copy was probably *technically correct* (the worst kind of correct), in that "You have already voted to close this question" is true, and retracting your vote doesn't buy you another.

However, the copy you proposed makes way more sense - thanks for the suggestion - on it's way to prod environment near you!

Comment: I just got "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote" on a question where I didn't retract it but the question was reopened by others. The old message would have been correct. [This was reported soon after the change](/q/376335) and I don't understand why it still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @benrg why not fixed? Because they have more important things to do. Anyway since this change caused a bug it's bad.