# Incorrect message shown when trying to close a question a second time

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-dialog, retracted-close-votes

I voted to close a question on EL&U, and it was later closed. Then the question was reopened again. Now I can't cast another close vote, so why does the message say, "You cannot vote to close again after **retracting** your vote"? I never retracted my vote. This message should instead say, "You cannot cast a *second* close vote" or "You cannot vote to close a second time".

[image: Image of close dialog with incorrect message: "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote"]

For a question where I've actually retracted a vote, the message is correct:

[image: Image of close dialog with correct message: "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote"]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. You're probably thinking of the [question that's the exact opposite of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332817/323179). They seem to have overshot when they addressed that question, leading to this question.

Comment: @Laurel: It seems A Rogue Ant was talking about a question they had recently asked, but couldn't remember: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376335/when-a-retraction-is-not-a-retraction-please-update-close-menu-message

Comment: @Justin I knew it seemed familiar somehow....