# Misleading message claims I retracted my close vote on a question re-opened by others

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

When a [question](/q/394772/620615) I voted to close is re-opened by others, opening the close vote modal tells me that I cannot vote again after retracting my vote:

[image: Screenshot of the bug]

I am not really protesting that I cannot vote again (I wish I could have changed the vote reason to “duplicate”, but that’s beside the point), but the message is still wrong, as I have not retracted my vote.  I think the message should be changed.

(It seems the response to [Replace "You have already voted to close ...." after retracting vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332817/620615) has over-corrected.)

Comment: Already reported, and worth to mention it's direct result of [implementing a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332817/replace-you-have-already-voted-to-close-after-retracting-vote).

Comment: Oh well, indeed it’s a duplicate. How come it didn’t show up in the suggested duplicates search box?

Comment: Different words being used in title, so the  algorithm didn't catch it. e.g. yours is using "retracted" while the dupe has "retraction", dupe has "close-menu", yours has "close vote", etc.